# Magento 2 Extend class with custom method through preference doesn't work

Tags: magento-2.1, preference

I'm trying to add a custom method `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation`. To my knowledge preference is the only way to do that.

My `di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Navigation" />
</config>
```

My Navigation.php

```
<?php

 namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;

 class Navigation extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
 {
  public function customMethod() {
   ...code
  }
 }
```

I run magento setup:upgrade and compile but when i try to call the function i get nothing back. Putting the same function in core works fine, so nothing wrong with the function itself.

```
<?php var_dump($block->customMethod()); ?>
```

Returns NULL

I've seen a bunch of questions from people having problems regarding this but not any satisfying solutions.

Comment: try to run di:compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got this to work and this is how I did it.

Apparently Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\ is never used by itself but is used by two virtual types in Magento/LayeredNavigation/etc/frontend/di.xml.

- Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category
- Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Search

So in my case I actually had to create my own virtual type based on my class that extends Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation and use that virtual type as preference for the virtual type created in core.

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
...
<virtualType name="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Navigation\Category" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Navigation">
    <arguments>
         <argument name="filterList" xsi:type="object">categoryFilterList</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Navigation\Category" />
...
</config>
```

Navigation.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;

class Navigation extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
{

 public function customMethod()
 {
   ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are trying to override Magento Layered navigation block. Your `di.xml` should be like below:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Macforum\MultipleLayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" />
</config>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry...that was just a typo when i wrote the question...edited the question. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

As you want to overide the class `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation`

So your preference class should be

> for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation"

**instead of**

> for="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Navigation"

***Please do the recommend changes*** at `di.xml`.

And **`Macforum\MultipleLayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation`** code should be:

---

```
<?php

namespace Macforum\MultipleLayeredNavigation\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;

/**
 * Catalog navigation
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Navigation extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Category
     */
    protected $_categoryInstance;

    /**
     * Current category key
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_currentCategoryKey;

    /**
     * Array of level position counters
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_itemLevelPositions = [];

    /**
     * Catalog category
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    protected $_catalogCategory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /**
     * Customer session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog layer
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
     */
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State
     */
    protected $flatState;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $flatState
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $flatState,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->_catalogCategory = $catalogCategory;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->flatState = $flatState;
        $this->_categoryInstance = $categoryFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(
            [
                'cache_lifetime' => false,
                'cache_tags' => [Category::CACHE_TAG, \Magento\Store\Model\Group::CACHE_TAG],
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get current category
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $shortCacheId = [
            'CATALOG_NAVIGATION',
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
            $this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_GROUP),
            'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
            'name' => $this->getNameInLayout(),
            $this->getCurrentCategoryKey(),
        ];
        $cacheId = $shortCacheId;

        $shortCacheId = array_values($shortCacheId);
        $shortCacheId = implode('|', $shortCacheId);
        $shortCacheId = md5($shortCacheId);

        $cacheId['category_path'] = $this->getCurrentCategoryKey();
        $cacheId['short_cache_id'] = $shortCacheId;

        return $cacheId;
    }

    /**
     * Get current category key
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentCategoryKey()
    {
        if (!$this->_currentCategoryKey) {
            $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
            if ($category) {
                $this->_currentCategoryKey = $category->getPath();
            } else {
                $this->_currentCategoryKey = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
            }
        }

        return $this->_currentCategoryKey;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve child categories of current category
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection
     */
    public function getCurrentChildCategories()
    {
        $categories = $this->_catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->_catalogLayer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
        $productCollection->addCountToCategories($categories);
        return $categories;
    }

    /**
     * Checkin activity of category
     *
     * @param   \Magento\Framework\DataObject $category
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function isCategoryActive($category)
    {
        if ($this->getCurrentCategory()) {
            return in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathIds());
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get url for category data
     *
     * @param Category $category
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryUrl($category)
    {
        if ($category instanceof Category) {
            $url = $category->getUrl();
        } else {
            $url = $this->_categoryInstance->setData($category->getData())->getUrl();
        }

        return $url;
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory();
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::CACHE_TAG, \Magento\Store\Model\Group::CACHE_TAG];
    } 
    public function customMethod() {
    //...code
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass this inside __construct() like

```
protected $_navigation

public function __construct(
...
\Macforum\MultipleLayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation $navigation
...
){
$this->_navigation = $navigation;
}
```

Then in your class use

```
$this->_navigation->customMethod();
```

Also you better put your custom functionality inside "Helper" directory or "Resolver", not inside a "Block".